# Could we do this kind of UI with Ext.Carousel?

Tags: css, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I would like to build a component like this:

[image: carousel]

Each image in this chain is an item. When I swipe from left to right or vice-versa, the active item slides into the centre.
My question: could we have this done with Ext.Carousel? Or it should be better to use another component? Is it all of CSS styling or we have to override something in Sencha Touch component class definition? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone (elmasse) has created a extension for sencha touch. `Ext.ux.Cover`
You get get it on [github](https://github.com/elmasse/Ext.ux.Cover). Forum post [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?140773-Ext.ux.Cover-Coverflow-extension-for-Sencha-Touch). [Example here](http://bit.ly/SenchaCover).

That doesn't completely answer your question because you want to make your own. He extended his view from a `Ext.DataView` and uses CSS3 3d transforms for the animations.